# After creating a custom user with django when i tried to create a user my password don't show or its Blank or you can say its none

Tags: python, html, django

**My django custom user return blank or none as password after creating a user but I can't find any
problem I am new at this I've done my research but it's hopeless so help me**

Here is my models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager


# Create your models here.

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, first_name, last_name,  date_of_birth, gender,  password=None):
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a first name")
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a last name")
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not gender:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a gender")
        if not date_of_birth:
            raise ValueError("You Must Enter your date of birth")

        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
            gender=gender,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, first_name, last_name,  date_of_birth, gender,  password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            email,
            first_name,
            last_name,
            date_of_birth,
            gender,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    gender_choices = [
        ("male", "Male"),
        ("female", "Female"),
        ("others", "Others")
    ]
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=gender_choices)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name',
                       'email', 'last_name',  'date_of_birth', 'gender']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def get_full_name(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

Here is my admin

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
# Register your models here.


from .models import MyUser


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password1 = forms.CharField(label="password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label="password confirmation", widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('username', "email", "first_name", "last_name",
                  "gender", "date_of_birth")

        def clean_password2(self):
            password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
            password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
            if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
                raise ValidationError("Password don't match")
            return password2

        def save(self, commit=True):
            user = super().save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
            if commit:
                user.save()
            return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    passwrod = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('username', "email", "first_name", "last_name",
                  "gender", "date_of_birth", 'is_active', "is_admin")

        def clean_password(self):
            return self.initial["password"]


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'password',
                    'last_name', 'is_admin', 'is_active')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            "fields": ('username', 'email', 'first_name',
                       'last_name', 'is_admin', 'is_active',  'date_of_birth', 'gender'),
        }),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            "fields": ('username', 'email', 'first_name',
                       'last_name', 'is_admin', 'is_active', 'password1', 'password2', 'date_of_birth', 'gender'),
        }),
    )

    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()


User = get_user_model()
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Here is my views

```
def registerUser(request):
    context = {}
    form = UserCreationForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if MyUser.objects.filter(email=request.POST.get('email')).count() == 1:
            messages.error(request, 'Email is already registerd.')
            return render(request, "register.html", {"form": form})
        elif MyUser.objects.filter(username=request.POST.get('username')).count() == 1:
            messages.error(
                request, "Username already in Use choce differnt one")
            return render(request, "register.html", {'form': form})
        else:
            if form.is_valid:
                form.save()
                return redirect("/")
    context["form"] = form
    return render(request, "register.html", context)
```

Here is my template

```
{% load static %}
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/login_and_register.css' %}" />
  <style>
    select {
      margin: 5px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    select option {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .error {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: rgb(243, 70, 70);
      font-size: 18px;
      text-align: center;
      transform: translateX(-100px);
    }
  </style>
</head>
<form action="{% url 'register' %}" id="registrationForm" method="POST">
  <h1 id="formHeader">Register User</h1>
  <p>This Register is page for only Staff</p>
  <div id="fields">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="username">User Name:</label>
    {{form.username}}
    <label for="firstname"> First Name: </label>
    {{form.first_name}}
    <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
    {{form.last_name}}
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    {{form.email}}
    <label for="password1">Password:</label>
    {{form.password1}}
    <label for="password2">Conform Password:</label>
    {{form.password2}}
    <label for="gender">Gender</label>
    {{form.gender}}
    <label for="Date">Date of Birth:</label>
    {{form.date_of_birth}}
    <div></div>
    <div id="message"></div>
    {% if messages %}
    <div></div>
    <ul class="messages">
      {% for message in messages %}
      <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}" {% endif %}>
        {% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.ERROR %}Important: {% endif %}
        {{ message }}
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
  <p>If you already have an Account click <a href="">Log-In</a></p>
  <button type="submit" id="submitBtn">Create User</button>
</form>
<script>
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
  inputs[1].placeholder = "Enter your User Name";
  inputs[2].placeholder = "Enter Your First Name";
  inputs[3].placeholder = "Enter Your Last Name";
  inputs[4].placeholder = "Enter Your Email Id";
  inputs[5].placeholder = "Enter Your Password";
  //inputs[5].setAttribute("type", "password");
  inputs[6].placeholder = "Re-enter Your Password";
  inputs[7].setAttribute("type", "date");
  document
    .getElementById("registrationForm")
    .addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
      let messeges;
      let condition = true;
      if (inputs[5].value != inputs[6].value) {
        condition = false;
        messeges = "Password didn't matched";
        document.getElementById("message").innerText =
          "Password didn't matched";
        document.getElementById("message").classList.add("error");
      } else if (inputs[5].value == inputs[6].value) {
        condition = true;
      }
      if (condition == false) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      console.log(condition);
    });
</script>
```

**when I create a user my password didn't get added to database**

Answer (score 0):

Look like u're trying to override `UserCreationForm` and `UserChangeForm`. If so, well you don't need to do that even you extended User model because default `UserCreationForm` already handled the password validation for you and all you need to do is declare the password1 and password2 in the form class.

Create a new file called `forms.py`.

**forms.py**

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

# import MyUser model
from .models import MyUser

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = MyUser
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', ..] # your MyUser fields
```

views.py

```py
from .forms import UserRegisterForm

def registerUser(request):
    context = {}
    form = UserRegisterForm() # change here
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST) # change here
        if MyUser.objects.filter(email=request.POST.get('email')).count() == 1:
            messages.error(request, 'Email is already registerd.')
            return render(request, "register.html", {"form": form})
        elif MyUser.objects.filter(username=request.POST.get('username')).count() == 1:
            messages.error(
                request, "Username already in Use choce differnt one")
            return render(request, "register.html", {'form': form})
        else:
            if form.is_valid:
                form.save()
                return redirect("/")
    context["form"] = form
    return render(request, "register.html", context)
```